# Working in cakephp trying to implement a login form in layout title bar

Tags: cakephp

Very strange... I cant get the login form to work, but if I put it in twice the second set of the form seams to work.

```
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                        <div class="form-group">



                            <?php if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')): ?>
                                <?php
                                print
                                        'Welcome back ' . $this->Session->read('Auth.User.name') . '' .
                                        $this->Html->link('Logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
                                ?>
                            <?Php else: ?>




                                <?php
                                echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
                                    'action' => 'login',
                                    'class' => 'form-inline',
                                    'role' => 'form',
                                    'inputDefaults' => array(
                                        'div' => array('class' => 'form-group'),
                                        'class' => array('form-control'),
                                        'label' => false,
                                        'wrapInput' => false
                                )));
                                ?>



                                <?php
                                echo $this->Form->input('username', array(
                                    'placeholder' => 'Username'
                                ));
                                ?>
                                <?php
                                echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
                                    'placeholder' => 'Password'
                                ));
                                ?>  

<?php
echo $this->Form->submit('Sign in', array(
    'div' => 'form-group',
    'class' => 'btn btn-success'
));
?>

                                <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
                            <?php
                                echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
                                    'action' => 'login',
                                    'class' => 'form-inline',
                                    'role' => 'form',
                                    'inputDefaults' => array(
                                        'div' => array('class' => 'form-group'),
                                        'class' => array('form-control'),
                                        'label' => false,
                                        'wrapInput' => false
                                )));
                                ?>



                                <?php
                                echo $this->Form->input('username', array(
                                    'placeholder' => 'Username'
                                ));
                                ?>
                                <?php
                                echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
                                    'placeholder' => 'Password'
                                ));
                                ?>  

<?php
echo $this->Form->submit('Sign in', array(
    'div' => 'form-group',
    'class' => 'btn btn-success'
));
?>

                                <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>




                                <!--//    echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login', 'class' => 'form-inline'));     
                                //        echo $this->Form->input('username');
                                //        echo $this->Form->input('password');   
                                //     echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); 
                                -->

            <?php endif; ?>

                        </div>
                    </form>
```

This works 100% but this (below) doesn't:

```
   <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                        <div class="form-group">



                            <?php if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')): ?>
                                <?php
                                print
                                        'Welcome back ' . $this->Session->read('Auth.User.name') . '' .
                                        $this->Html->link('Logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
                                ?>
                            <?Php else: ?>





                            <?php
                                echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
                                    'action' => 'login',
                                    'class' => 'form-inline',
                                    'role' => 'form',
                                    'inputDefaults' => array(
                                        'div' => array('class' => 'form-group'),
                                        'class' => array('form-control'),
                                        'label' => false,
                                        'wrapInput' => false
                                )));
                                ?>



                                <?php
                                echo $this->Form->input('username', array(
                                    'placeholder' => 'Username'
                                ));
                                ?>
                                <?php
                                echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
                                    'placeholder' => 'Password'
                                ));
                                ?>  

<?php
echo $this->Form->submit('Sign in', array(
    'div' => 'form-group',
    'class' => 'btn btn-success'
));
?>

                                <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>




                                <!--//    echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login', 'class' => 'form-inline'));     
                                //        echo $this->Form->input('username');
                                //        echo $this->Form->input('password');   
                                //     echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); 
                                -->

            <?php endif; ?>

                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why this would happen? I'm sure I had it working last night but I cant seam to get it to work today. I can add more code if required. Note I am using boostcake plugin but have disabled its helpers in appController, and removed it in bootstrap and no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a bit stupid but the problem was that I used a form html element instead of a div, this must somehow affect the way cake builds forms. I would love to know more about this if someone has an answer. Constructive comments will be appreciated.